# Handling Historical Money on Shabbat

Tags: halacha, shabbat, money, muktzeh

Let's say a historian had a collection of Bar Kochba coins or even replicas of those coins. Since these coins serve zero purpose as money today, can they be handled on Shabbat?

Comment: Do they serve any purpose at all today? Any reason why they wouldn't be muktzeh just as much as regular money?

Comment: The coinage would serve no purpose other than being historically interesting. i've seen people bring out very old silver kiddush cups to admire, or very old books, and so i wondered, what about ancient israelite coins?

Comment: That's my point. If it serves no purpose, then it's _muktzeh_ (perhaps even worse than if it has an _assur_ purpose i.e. a _kli shemelachto l'issur_ [I'm not saying that's what money is; I'm not sure]). Whether being historically interesting is sufficient purpose for the money to not be _muktzeh_ remains to be seen.